# Emacs org-mode: refile using the goto-interface

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I often use the capture-refile-archive structure of org-mode but I have problem with the way the refiling works. I use IDO completion so that when I refile a tree `C-c C-w` I get all the possible trees to refile under in the mini-buffer.

However, this results in a huge number of possible completions that really aren't very readable. It would be far better if you could choose a refile file location and then use the `org-goto-interface` temporary buffer to choose a particular subtree.

Does anybody know how this could be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the settings you are looking for are

```
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
(setq org-outline-path-complete-in-steps t)
```

`org-refile-use-outline-path` lets you give the refile targets as paths (`file.org/heading/subheading`) and `org-outline-path-complete-in-steps` will pause after competing each stage of  the path.  Start refiling, type the path and press `[tab]` to get a list of all the top level headlines.  Continue to the location you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Its a shame that it doesn't work with the `org-completion-use-ido`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `org-refile-targets` before running
`org-refile`. For example, I've
[described](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213094847/https://kyleam.com/posts/dynamic-org-refile-targets/) doing
this for selecting and refiling to Org files that aren't in the global
`org-refile-targets`. That was focused on having functions other than
`org-refile` to handle special cases, but if you wanted `org-refile` to
always ask for a buffer or file to refile to, you could advise
`org-refile` to override `org-refile-targets` or you could set
`org-refile-targets` to a function that returns a selected buffer.

```
(defun km/get-open-org-file ()
  (buffer-file-name
   (get-buffer
    (org-icompleting-read "Buffer: "
                          (mapcar 'buffer-name
                                  (org-buffer-list 'files))))))

(setq org-refile-targets '((km/get-open-org-file . (:maxlevel . 2))))
```

How exactly you set up `org-refile-targets` depends a lot on your work
flow and structure for notes, but those examples hopefully give you an
idea of how you can get things working the way you want.

Comment: That is a helpful start for determining how to show the refile targets before refiling but I'm not particularly interested in having dynamic refile locations. The larger problem that I would like to solve is using the `org-goto-interface` to select a subtree to refile to.

Comment: Perhaps this functionality doesn't exist, if not, I might try and implement it but I thought it was worth asking.

Comment: Sorry, looking back at that, my answer focused on "choose a refile file location" and ignored the clear focus on using `org-goto-interface`. I don't think that functionality exists. It might be tricky to implement because `org-goto` relies on `org-refile` underneath.