# Org-refile with ido, not using ido as the completion engine

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, ido

I'm trying to setup a capture/refile workflow using org-mode, and I'm having trouble getting ido working as the completion engine.

I have ido enabled:

```
(require 'ido)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(ido-mode t)
```

And then later in my configuration I try to setup ido completion with `org-refile` using the following configuration

```
(setq org-agenda-files
      '("~/org/captured.org"
        "~/org/work.org"
        "~/org/learning.org"
        "~/org/life.org"))
(setq org-refile-targets '((nil :maxlevel . 6)
                           (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 6)))
(setq org-refile-use-outline-path 'file)
(setq org-completion-use-ido t)
```

I would expect that with these settings, when I try to call `org-refile` I would be presented with an ido completion interface in the minibuffer, listing the files and headings that I can refile to, structured like a directory tree.

What I see, however, is just a blank space, like the non-ido completion interface. I am able to do completion with this interface. For example I can type `wo[Tab]em[Tab]` to get `work/email`, but I would much prefer ido.

Is there something wrong with how I've configured this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some further poking, and reading on StackOverflow, I realized what the problem was.

I had been experimenting with the variable `org-outline-path-complete-in-steps` and I had set it to `t` at some point. Making sure that this variable was set to `nil` allowed ido to work as I expected.

Thanks to this answer for helping me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26682891/173292